# Can I make a hit counter from this?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a personal wiki and have always wanted to add a personal hit counter, something that isn't from a third party. I know you can use php and can do it locally through JavaScript but in this wiki platform you don't have access to that information.

However I was able to find this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="randomnumbersandtext">
```

Which is directly associated with how they track views. Is there anyway I could use this to track views? Could I also just use javascript to track this page with all the view information and display it on a different one? Also any information about how to track views would be nice, I don't know much about it.

Comment: use the weblogs from the server?

Comment: @nomistic what is that?

Comment: The place where all web traffic is stored by default.  Hit counters are unnecessary.  Also there's no need to reinvent the wheel;  your webserver probably already provides you with some basic stats (typically something like AWStats).  Failing that,  google analytics will do the same thing for you.   It's much more accurate than a "counter"

Comment: @nomistic oh wow I'm an internet noob I didn't know that was a thing, thanks.

Comment: Google analytics, text file, database.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to do it yourself. You can use php to insert a visitors ip in a mysql database. You can then count the number of rows and display it back :)

Comment: So you're saying run a second database and then just insert it into the website?